# Hermite-Gauss Quadrates Error Bound

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

Using Hermite-Gauss Quadrates to approximate the integral $I = \int_0^\infty e^{ -x^2} f(x) \, dx $, the error is given as
$$
E = \frac{m!\sqrt{\pi}}{2^m (2m)!} f^{(2m)}(\theta)
$$
with $0 < \theta  < \infty $. However, this estimation is not practical since in some cases we cant know $f^{(2m)}(\theta)$. So are there any ways to determine that error or bounds of that one?

Answer (score 2):

Many times we know that $|f^{(2 m)}(\theta)|$ is bounded.  For example, $f(x) = \sin{(a x)}$ implies that $|f^{(2 m)}(\theta)| < a^{2 m}$.  In this case, the error is bounded and we may say that the error in using Hermite-Gauss quadrature to this order is less than some number, which is valuable.